# How to create a tab that contains a custom LWC, but is not part of an app?

Tags: lightning, tab

I have a link in an external system that redirects users to Salesforce. The link opens a tab with a custom LWC. I'd like to have this tab/page accessible to those users without creating this tab/page as part of a Lightning App. Is that possible?

Comment: There's a special type of LWC target called `lightning__Tab` that allows an LWC to be used as a Salesforce UI tab (the advantage is that this removes the header block from the tab content). You'll have to create a custom tab that maps to this LWC. I think such custom tabs can be outside a Lightning App.

Comment: @PhilW You've got my gratitude, Phil.